# Conexión de formulario de registro con base de datos php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

`

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bd_prueba");
   if (!$conexion){
        echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos';
    }
else {
    echo 'Conectado a la base de datos';
}
```

```html
<?php
include 'cn.php';
//Recibir los datos y almacenarlos en variables
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$clave = $_POST["clave"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
// Consulta para insertar
$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos, correo, usuario, clave, telefono) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$correo', '$usuario', '$clave', '$telefono')";

$verificar_usuario = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = 'usuario'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar_usuario) > 0){
    echo 'El usuario ya esta registrado';
    exit;
}
//Ejecutar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if (!$resultado){
    echo 'Error al registrarse';

}else {
    echo'Usuario registrado exitosamente';
}
//Cerrar conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

`Estoy haciendo un formulario de registro, y al momento de ejecutar la acción de guardar los datos en la base de datos me dice que no se pudo, esto lo se gracias a que yo programé que cuando no se pudierá me mandará un mensaje de "Error al  registrase".
En el código **validar.js**, me marca que ***`alert`*** no esta definido, también que ***`document`*** no esta definido, pero yo no los ocupo como variables y también me dice que ***`function`*** esta definida pero nunca usada. ¿Qué puedo hacer?
Aquí les dejo mis códigos.

```js
function validar() {
    var nombre, apellidos, correo, usuario, clave, telefono, expresion;
    nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
    correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
    usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
    clave = document.getElementById("clave").value;
    telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
    
    expresion = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;
    

    if(nombre === "" || apellidos === "" || correo === "" || usuario === "" || clave =="" || telefono === ""){
 alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
return false;     

}
    else if(nombre.length>50) {
        alert("El nombre es muy largo");
        return false;
    }
        else if(apellidos.length>100) {
        alert("Los apellidos son muy largos");
        return false;    
    }
        else if(correo.length>40) {
        alert("El correo es muy largo");
        return false;    
    }
    else if(!expresion.test(correo)){
      alert("El correo no es valido");
        return false;   
    }
        else if(usuario.length>18) {
        alert("El usuario es muy largo");
        return false;    
    }
        else if(clave.length>20) {
        alert("La clave es muy larga");
        return false;    
    }
        else if(telefono.length>15) {
        alert("El telefono es muy largo");
        return false;    
    }
        else if(isNaN(telefono)) {
        alert("El telefono ingresado no es un número");
        return false;    
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario de registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <script src="validar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Formulario de registro </h1>
        <form action="registrar.php" method="post" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar();">
            <h2 class="form__titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
            <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="input-48" required>
                <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" class="input-48" required>
                <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" class="input-100" required>
                <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" class="input-48" required>
                <input type="password" id="clave" name="clave" placeholder="Contraseña" class="input-48" required>
                <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" class="input-100" required>
                <input type="submit" id="registrar" value="Registrar" class="btn-enviar">
                <p class="from__link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? 
                    <a href="#" >Ingresa aqui</a></p>    
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
introducir el código aquí
```

introducir el código aquí

Comment: Olvide colocar unos codigos, los anexare aqui, los 2 son ,php

Comment: <?php
include 'cn.php';

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$clave = $_POST["clave"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos, correo, usuario, clave, telefono) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$correo', '$usuario', '$clave', '$telefono')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if (!$resultado){
    echo 'Error al registrarse';
}else {
    echo'Usuario registrado exitosamente';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

Comment: <?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bd_prueba");

Comment: no los anexes aquí, no se entiende, edita la pregunta y pégalos ahí

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta para añadir contenido o mejorar la pregunta utilizando el link de editar en la parte baja de la pregunta o pulsando aqui: [edit]. Tambien te recomendaria que hicieras el [tour] y revises [ask]. Un saludo y bienvenido a SOes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya esta editado, los archivos que añadi son .php

Answer (score 1):

modifica un poco tu codigo y verifica tu conexion con la base de datos

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bd_prueba");//faltan datos en esta conexion

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "bd_prueba" );//correcto
   if (!$conexion){
        echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos';
    }
else {
    echo 'Conectado a la base de datos';
}

<?php
include 'cn.php';
//Recibir los datos y almacenarlos en variables
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$clave = $_POST["clave"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];

//en esta consulta te falto el $ en usuario 
$verificar_usuario = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = 'usuario'");

$verificar_usuario = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");//correcto


if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar_usuario) > 0){
    echo 'El usuario ya esta registrado';
    exit;
}else{

$insertar =mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos, correo, usuario, clave, telefono) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$correo', '$usuario', '$clave', '$telefono')");


if (!$insertar){
    echo 'Error al registrarse';

}else {
    echo'Usuario registrado exitosamente';
}





}




//Cerrar conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);
```